# An ascii character is 8 bytes , how would the converted word be stored in 32bytes

Tags: math, ascii

Since Ascii is 8 bytes the converted word would be stored by 4 ,4 ,4 ,4, 4, 4, 4 ,4
 or would i just padd zero's, i dont think i would have an issue fitting in the converted word since the size for the word would be 32bytes > 8 bytes

This is what i gathered : In a logical shift, the empty positions are filled with 0's. If you shift a word 32 or more bits, it will contain all 0's.

What do you think ? i think im right since all it would be is logical shift

Comment: Please be aware bytes != bits. An ASCII character is 1 byte (8 bits).

Comment: @vcsjones ASCII is 7 bits http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 0):

Ascii characters are not 8 bytes, they are 8 bits. And I doubt your machine word is 32 bytes. Other than that I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Well let me try to be a bit more clearer .. Considering the fact that each ASCII character is stored on 8 bits,  how
would you fit your converted number into a 32-bit word
, hopefully that makes more sense